# Why does my JS web app cause Firefox CPU usage when doing nothing?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cpu-usage

I've created a complex JavaScript web app. It works very well and is fast. But I've noticed that Firefox is continuously using the CPU while the app is open in the browser window but not doing anything. I haven't programmed in any setIntervals, setTimeouts, automatic regular requests to the server - nothing. The only thing it has is the GUI, which is already instantiated and sitting there doing nothing (since the last interaction with the user), and the event handlers which are waiting, attached to various GUI controls. Just to make sure, I used the profiler in Firebug and it confirmed that there was no activity to profile.

I did have 3 FF add-ons running: Avast Online Security, Firebug, and Web Developer. I have disabled these, and it seems to have reduced the CPU useage from say 4-5% to 1-2%. I know this is low, but considering I have only one tab open with my app in it, I would like to know where that 1-2% is being used. The memory consumption is not increasing (it fluctuates, but doesn't increase over time). I have done some quick checks with IE (9) but the CPU usage tends to stay at 0%.

I can't provide any code or solid starting points, but I just thought someone might have some ideas.

Comment: Do you have any animated images?

Comment: I was going to say "no", but... I've just thought about it and I do use a typical rotating 'data loading' image. Need to check whether I remove this from the DOM, or whether I simply move it behind...

Comment: Note that just removing an image from the DOM may not stop it animating, depending on what else is going on.

Comment: Yes. The image element may still be assigned as the value of an object somewhere - is that what you mean? So far I've managed to check the code for this and it seems that I always use the delete operator on it. I've also viewed the DOM in Firebug and the image is definitely no longer in it.